# I want to put the symbol percent %

Tags: symbols, unicode

When I try to put the symbol %, an error is returned. My code is:

```
casi el 25\%
```

which results in the error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char × (U+D7)
(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Comment: the error message is about  `×` not about `%`, what makes you think it is related to the line that you show?

Comment: This question does not seem related to biblatex either

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are right!!!

Comment: sometimes that happens:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `siunitx` package provides nice functions to typeset units, as well as percentages.

Do `\SI{25}{\percent}` to obtain what you need.

Comment: this is sort of true but would not help with the error message shown in the question.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree ... However, it answers the question exactly.

Comment: well... the code in the question `casi el 25\%` also answers the question exactly in that sense.